# Regex which puts more importance on some types

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match city, state, zip but all of them are optional.
The rule is, if I find 5 digits, it's a zip. If I find 2 letters, it's a state.
The rest is the city.

The delimiters can be spaces, comma, and ugly periods could be in the way.

I came up with this:

```
^(?<CITY>[A-Z ]*)[ ,]+(?<STATE>[A-Z]{2})?\.?([ ,]+(?<ZIP>[0-9]{5}))?$
```

```
SEATTLE  WA 98103
WALNUT CREEK CA 98103
WALNUT CREEK, CA, 98103
WALNUT CREEK, CA
WALNUT CREEK, 98103
SEATTLE, WA. 98103
SEATTLE  WA, 98103
98103
WA 98103
SEATTLE
```

But it doesn't put emphases on the ZIP and State rule. So I'm missing a couple scenarios. The last 4 are not working.

How can I enforce this rule? Some atomic? Some look ahead?

Comment: The point is to combine lazy matching with the first group + optional non-capturing groups with obligatory patterns (with the 2nd and 3rd named groups) inside + boundaries to make sure the second and third groups are matched when they are present as whole words. Atomic groups would prevent backtracking here, they won't help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?<CITY>[A-Z ]*?)(?:[ ,]*\b(?<STATE>[A-Z]{2})\.?)?(?:[ ,]*\b(?<ZIP>[0-9]{5}))?$
```

Or, if the CITY part may contain any chars, replace `[A-Z ]*?` with `.*?`. Replace the literal space with `\s` to match any whitespace chars.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<CITY>[A-Z ]*?)` - a CITY group: any 0+ uppercase ASCII letters or spaces, as few as possible
- `(?:[ ,]*\b(?<STATE>[A-Z]{2})\.?)?` - an optional pattern matching

  - `[ ,]*` - zero or more spaces or commas
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(?<STATE>[A-Z]{2})` - STATE group: two uppercase ASCII letters
  - `\.?` - an optional dot
- `(?:[ ,]*\b(?<ZIP>[0-9]{5}))?` - an optional pattern matching:

  - `[ ,]*` - zero or more spaces or commas
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(?<ZIP>[0-9]{5})` - ZIP group: five digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3cCITY%3e%5bA-Z+%5d*%3f%29%28%3f%3a%5b+%2c%5d*%5cb%28%3f%3cSTATE%3e%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%29%5c.%3f%29%3f%28%3f%3a%5b+%2c%5d*%5cb%28%3f%3cZIP%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b5%7d%29%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=SEATTLE++WA+98103%0d%0aWALNUT+CREEK+CA+98103%0d%0aWALNUT+CREEK%2c+CA%2c+98103%0d%0aWALNUT+CREEK%2c+CA%0d%0aWALNUT+CREEK%2c+98103%0d%0aSEATTLE%2c+WA.+98103%0d%0aSEATTLE++WA%2c+98103%0d%0a98103%0d%0aWA+98103%0d%0aSEATTLE&o=m). Output:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I just made them separators optionals

```
^(?<CITY>[A-Z ]*)?([ ,]+)?(?<STATE>[A-Z]{2})?\.?(([ ,]+)?(?<ZIP>[0-9]{5}))?$
```

See [This regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0vkHDB/1)

Comment: Please don't link to external sites like this. Please put a full answer in the question - showing input, output, code, and an explanation - and only then link to external sites to provide support for your content.

Comment: I have put the full answer (the regex) and I have linked to the regex site that shows the regex being applied to the example the OP has shared to exemplify how the regex is applied to it to each row of his data. What is wrong there?

Comment: Please explain the regex and the show how the regex is applied in your answer. You should have a complete answer before linking anywhere. External links can become broken so they are strongly discouraged.

Comment: That Regex does not work. You see that you match almost everything as a City.